# Is a VirtualBox guest isolated from the host?

Tags: virtualization, isolation

I have a Linux machine running Kubuntu 20.10.

I have installed VirtualBox 6.1. I then created a virtual machine on which I have installed Windows 10.

Suppose an hacker enters in my Windows 10 guest.

Will he be able to see the files of my Kubuntu host (I mean, the files not in the shared folders, of course)?

How does the answer changes if on the guest machine I have the VirtualBox add-ons installed?

Comment: Probably not, but you can never be sure. Also please refrain from adding excessive tags that are not related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is isolation between the VM and the host this isolation is not perfect. Compared to using two different physical machines it is sufficient if the attacker can use a security issue in the hypervisor to escape out of the VM.

Such security issues are often in parts of the hypervisor where interaction between the VM host and the VM is done, i.e. emulated drivers etc. Guest additions also have such code, which means that they additionally increase the attack surface. Such vulnerabilities were found in the past, see for example [10 new VM escape vulnerabilities discovered in VirtualBox](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-new-vm-escape-vulnerabilities-discovered-in-virtualbox/).